# What does :: mean in front of a function call?

Tags: c++

```
I2CDevice::I2CDevice(unsigned int bus, unsigned int device) {
    this->file=-1;
    this->bus = bus;
    this->device = device;
    this->open();
}

int I2CDevice::open(){
   string name;
   if(this->bus==0) name = BBB_I2C_0;
   else name = BBB_I2C_1;

   if((this->file=::open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 0){
      perror("I2C: failed to open the bus\n");
      return 1;
   }

   if(ioctl(this->file, I2C_SLAVE, this->device) < 0){
      perror("I2C: Failed to connect to the device\n");
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The above is part of a code doing Linux I2C interface, my question is in the line:

```
this->file=::open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR)
```

I think this is trying to assign a value to the file descriptor this->file using open() function. But why there is a "::" symbol? Why not just "open()".

Comment: I've updated the title and the tags because this actually has nothing to do with `open` specifically, but if you disagree, you can undo my changes.

Comment: @immibis accepted, thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is C++ name resolution. The `::` operator separates namespaces. When it starts a name, it is an explicit reference to the top level, global namespace. Its use here guarantees that it is referring to the `open` function declared by the C library and not any `open` that happens to be in the class, the current namespace, or any `using namespace` declarations.

In this specific example, `::open` is required because it is inside an `open` class function. Simply calling `open` here would cause a name resolution error because there's an `open` in the class but no matching override. If the arguments **did** match, it would be a recursive call which isn't what you want.

Comment: typo correction: "... no matching *overload*."